# Windows Phone PhoneGap App should not be zoomable

Tags: c#, javascript, css, cordova, windows-phone

I am developing Windows Phone PhoneGap app. Now the app is zoomable. I want the app to be not zoomable. Any help is appreciated. I tried `<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">`
and `<body style="-ms-touch-action: none;">`, they did not work.

Comment: Did you try anything to solve your problem? Show your work. Tell people what have you tried. Be more specific about your problems. Please read [FAQ]

Answer (score 1):

This may help you:

> When you package an Enyo (or any HTML app) on WP7, the native
>   WebBrowser control is used as the wrapper for your content. Like other
>   platforms, you have the option of setting your viewport to control
>   whether or not the user can pinch/zoom.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no">
```

http://forums.enyojs.com/discussion/353/windows-phone-7-disabling-the-default-pinch-zoom-scroll-snapback-behavior

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this meta tag in the `head` section of the page.

```
<meta
  name="viewport"
  content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your css. This solved the problem for me.

```
* {
    zoom:1;
    -ms-content-zooming:none;
}
```